# Making an iframe draggable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, iframe

I'm attempting to make a chat widget draggable, which I've successfully managed to do via `react-draggable`. However, this chat widget is also consumed by an iframe, which is entirely created via HTML. So I would need the iframe to also be draggable, but this package doesn't work with `react-draggable`. Are there any pure JS solutions to make this type behavior work?

The skeleton of my iframe example roughly looks like:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe class="iframe">
     #shadowRoot \\ all the react code 
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Related reading https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#the-draggable-attribute

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you should be able to do this via html.

```html
<div class="iframe-container" draggable=“true”>
  <iframe class="iframe">
     #shadowRoot \\ all the react code 
  </iframe>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant the `iframe` not the element containing it.